# How to set the background color of the "dxg:GridColumn" ?

Tags: wpf, devexpress

In the process of use "dxg:GridControl", I have a few problems.
It seems to be a very simple question, but I can 't going out to solve how it.

1,How to set the background color of the  "dxg:GridColumn"  ?
I want to set the background color of the "dxg:GridColumn"  ,which Header name is "Header2".What should I do?

```
<dxg:GridControl HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="gridControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" ShowBorder="False" DesignTimeDataSourceRowCount="0" Height="28" Width="{Binding Width,ElementName=gc1}" Margin="0">
        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Header1" Width="710" />
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Header2" Width="470" />
        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView ShowGroupPanel="False"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
```

2,How to add Autogenerated Serial Number GridColum in  "dxg:GridControl"?
 such as (in winforms):

```
private void gridView1_CustomDrawRowIndicator(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowIndicatorCustomDrawEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Info.IsRowIndicator && e.RowHandle >= 0)
   {
      e.Info.DisplayText = e.RowHandle.ToString();
    }
}
```

thx.

Answer (score 1):

first part of your question you can solve via `CellTemplate`:

```
<dxg:GridColumn Header="Header2" Width="470">
    <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Background="Red"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
</dxg:GridColumn>
```

second part: You want to add it at run-time? or you already have field for autogenerated gridcolumn? It would be better you to put here some some details to me which help to answer your question.

**EDIT**

So, exact solution I can't give you, because I'm not sure I understand you right. I think that you can bind your cell to the GridControl, and use the RowIndex[I dont know how its call] property or somthing like that.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Border Background="Blue">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=YourGridControl, Path=RowIndex}">
    </Border>
</DateTemplate>
```

Comment: About the second question,i don't know how can i description it.i am not good at english.
In fact it is not I add columns, but to use the "dxg: GridControl" left-most column of the system. There are arrows that indicate which line you choose to tell the column. I want the arrow in the back of that with the instructions to add line numbers.